# Javascript "switch statement" getting test value from a "input type text" using the getElementstByName.value

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to test 7 possible values of variable 'a', which is passed to my function from the values entered into seven 'input type text' boxes,  and then individually executed by 7 'input type image' clicks.  I do not get a result nor do I get the 'switch default' action of an alert box.  I have tried using getElementsById and also getElementsByName.
Here is the first two tests and default from the function:

```
function check_answer(a)
{
   var check = 0;

   switch (a)
   {
  case 1 :
     check = document.getElementById("blue").value;
     if(check == 21)
     {
        document.images[a].src = "ok.gif";
        score = score + 1000;
     }
     else
     {
        document.images[a].src = "wrong.gif";
        score = score - 500;
     }
     break;
  case 2 :
     check = document.getElementById("red").value;
     if(check == 22)
     {
        document.images[a].src = "ok.gif";
        score = score + 1000;
     }
     else
     {
        document.images[a].src = "wrong.gif";
        score = score - 500;
     }
     break;

  default :
     alert("fail";
   }
```

The input elements are in table data on 7 table rows of a table as below:

```
<td id="b">How many BLUE triangles?</td>
<td><input type = "text" id = "blue"></td>
<td><input type = "image" id="bb" src="q.gif" height="25" width="25" onclick =     "check_answer(1)">
<td width=10%><img src ="empty.gif" width="25" height="25"</td>
</td>
```

...... for 6 additional table rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a list of elements, you can't use `value` on it like that.

You'd get the first element returned from the list in this case, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByName("blue")[0].value;
```

I've corrected your Javascript and sorted out the stray HTML markup below.

**HTML:**

```
<td id="b">How many BLUE triangles?</td>
<td><input type = "text" name = "blue"/></td>
<td><input type = "image" id="bb" src="q.gif" height="25" width="25" onclick ="check_answer(1)"/>
<td width="10%"><img src ="empty.gif" width="25" height="25"/></td>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function check_answer(a){
  var check = 0;
  switch (a) {
      case 1:
         check = document.getElementsByName("blue")[0].value;
         break;
      case 2:
         check = document.getElementsByName("red")[0].value;
         if(check == 22) {
            document.images[a].src = "ok.gif";
            score = score + 1000;
         }
         else {
            document.images[a].src = "wrong.gif";
            score = score - 500;
         }
         break; 
   default: alert("fail");
   }    
}
```

Comment: I meant to use getElementById("").value, not getElementsByName("").  Made those changes and still doesn't work.  I put the full program on my website so you can see what I am trying to do. Take a look at www.midaslink.com/triangle.htm

Comment: @Rellif My code works fine, you have syntax errors on your website, check the console. Also you have HTML markup that isn't closed or anything.

Comment: @Rellif Have you fixed the other syntax errors in your website code yet? Got this problem fixed or?

Comment: My thanks to "Null".  Your code worked perfectly after I cleaned up my html miscues.  Thank you very much.  Here is the final product: [link](http://www.midaslink.com/triangle.htm)